# PowerShell suddenly hangs on executing any command

Tags: powershell

I'm on Windows 8.1 and have been using this particular Windows installation for about 3 years. I am not a heavy Powershell user per se, but I do some programming and any command line work (git, node) is typically done in Powershell - either the "built in" one or running the shell through ConEmu.

In the last few days, PowerShell started acting up. The window would hang on startup. So I tried removing all commands from my profile. Now at least I got to the prompt. However, if I try to enter a command such as

`cd src`

it will hang there, apparenty forever. The same if I do tab-completion.

Some commands work fine. The ones I have found are actual program files, such as git, node and ember. However, they don't help me a lot if I can't get to the directory I need to be in...

Set-Location has the same problem.

Windows is being kept up to date and I have no outstanding updates that are waiting.

Anything I can do to get my shell back? I'll try to answer any requests for system info but if they are to be found through PS commands I might need an alternative.

Thanks for any suggestions!

**Edit**: Checking the version actually worked.

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

**Edit 2**: Output of $PSVersionTable:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17400
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

**Edit 3**: After looking further at ProcMon, here is the last thing I see from any process containing "powershell" in the name after it has listed the contents of the directory:

[image: Screenshot of ProcMon events after powershell is frozen]

Comment: What version of Powershell?

Comment: v4, pasting in the question now.

Comment: What do you get if you try the command $PSVersionTable?

Comment: Added above. :)

Comment: Does the same problem occur if you run in the ISE?

Comment: Have you seen this: [http://superuser.com/questions/700786/powershell-periodically-hangs-after-any-command](http://superuser.com/questions/700786/powershell-periodically-hangs-after-any-command)?

Comment: No experience with ISE, but it seemed to not do much - i.e. "run" was not available. I did see that, but it didn't just hang for a while here, it never came back. Will try to use process monitor and see what it does.

Comment: I closed all poweshells, started procmon, and opened a shell. 42k events and I had a prompt. I tried the "dir" command and it actually listed the contents of the folder, but never returned. Nothing in ProcMon "jumped out".

Comment: Try to run `PowerShell.exe -noprofile`?

Comment: I did, and that worked 100% right now. So then I tried to run it without the -noprofile, and now that works 100% too... Very strange. It's been acting up for days.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Running the following commands in an elevated cmd prompt fixed it for me:

```
sfc /scannow
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

The first is the [System File Checker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e), which checks for and attempts to correct corrupted OS files.

The second, [DISM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/repair-a-windows-image), is used for online and offline Windows image manipulation. Using the /online switch tells it to use the live Windows environment currently running. This command will attempt to repair a corrupted Windows OS as well.

Comment: Hi jParnell, on this site we expect complete answers, where readers can see that the answer is correct, without having to look up references. You could improve your answer by explaining what teh commands do and maybe link command reference links for them.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have edited my answer to follow up.

Comment: The commands listed are in the [incorrect](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) order - `/RestoreHealth` must be run _prior_ to `/ScanNow`